# Как вывести результат функции пайтона в html используя библиотеку eel ? Web-интерфейс python

Tags: python, html, eel

Как вывести текст которую выдает пайтон функция main на экран програмы с помощью библиотеки eel? Тоесть нужно вывести результат функции main в html. И это нужно делать каждые 10 секунд

**Код пайтона**:

```py
import eel
import asyncio
from re import X
import aiohttp


eel.init("D:\Code\Python\Prog1\Web")

async def main():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        while True:
            print()
            os.system('CLS')
            async with session.get("https://scalpstation.com/api/futures/kdata?interval=1m&order=Trades15m&top=16") as resp:
                data = await resp.json()
                for monet in [x["Symbol"] for x in data["sorts"]]:
                    trades = [x for x in data["sorts"] if x["Symbol"] == monet][0]["Trades15m"]
                    value = 40000
                    if trades > value:
                        print( monet,':', trades )
        
            await asyncio.sleep(10)
    
eel.start("index.html", size=(700, 600))
```

**Код html** (дефолтный):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <script src="eel.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Как вывести текст которую выдает пайтон функция main на экран програмы с помощью библиотеки eel?

Comment: Почему вы выбрали для интерфейса eel? Вы разбераетесь в JS?

Comment: @СергейШашко К сожелению нет. Какое альтернативное решение вы можете предложить чтобы сделать гибкий/красивый интерфейс ?

Comment: Что первое приходит на ум это TKinter или PyQt. Масса уроков и примеров на просторах интернета, а если что-то пошло не так практически всегда можно найти решение.

Comment: а почему не работать через браузер? aiohttp позволяет же серверное приложение развернуть.

Comment: @СергейШашко Так и зделаю спасибо!